# Adding values on reclassified layers using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, reclassify

I have reclassified the values on the layer I am using, however, I would like to  add extra values. The final values showed in the layer should be in a scale from 0 to 10. That means, in this case, I have to add somehow values for 1, 2, 3, 4 and 10.

Can someone help me with this ArcMap problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to add a value to a unique values rendering for an INTEGER raster when the value does not exist in the raster.

Suggest you explore colormaps that may overcome this issue, search Help file for colormap.

Comment: Well, I tried but I didn't succeed! Do you think that I might try to repeat reclassification (Weighted Overlay)?

Comment: Thinking aloud, why do you want to symbolise values that don't exist in your dataset? It may be misleading? If you still want to do it and it is only for displaying on a map then you could consider editing the legend on a page layout, you would convert the legend to a graphic and edit accordingly.